# MVC routing: routing to a concrete method in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I couldn't get any good information on how to define a route to a contrete action in the selected controller. MSDN doesn't provide clean information on this. There is a mention of action parameter but it doesn't seem to be working.

What I want to achive is to route path like /vehicles/check*** to Check method in the VehiclesController.

A concrete invokation is  /vehicles/check?licencePlate=XYZ => 
VehiclesController -> Check(string licenePlate)

I have this map but it does not work:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("VehicleTransactions", "Vehicles/Check", 
            new { controller = "Vehicles", action= "Check" });
```

Can it be done with MVC?

Thanks, Radek

Comment: Can you route the whole controller instead ?

Comment: Are you routing to a `Controller` or `ApiController`? `MapHttpRoute` is for web api. Clarify which framework you are trying to call

Comment: I am routing to ApiController class.

Answer (score 1):

`MapHttpRoute` is used for mapping Web API routes. For MVC Controller routes we tend to use `MapRoute`

So Assuming

```
public class VehiclesController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Check(string licenePlate) {
        //...
        return View();
    }
}
```

The route would be mapped to

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "VehicleTransactions",
    url: "vehicles/check",
    defaults: new { controller = "Vehicles", action= "Check" }
);
```

Comment: I have exactly the same code as you recommended with the exception I am using MapHttpRoute not MapRoute, but as I stated in the question, this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
          name: "VehicleTransactions",
          url: "Vehicles/Check/{licencePlate}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Vehicles", action = "Check", licencePlate = UrlParameter.Optional });

routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Default",
         url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Set "VehicleTransactions" routing before of "Default" routing, because otherwise "Default" overwrite the other.

Special routes is set always before default routing.

Comment: The first route works. It does resolve path /vehicles/check/XYZ. I originally wanted however  /vehicles/check?licencePlate=XYZ to be resolved correctly, which still doesn't, I am afraid.

Comment: I tried it and it's works also with /vehicles/check?licencePlate=XYZ
Try to describe better your problem...